# Excel count amount of numbers separated by a comma with range from x to y

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have numbers separated by commas and also ranges of numbers (for example, 1-5 means 1,2,3,4,5). I would like to return the total quantity of numbers in the string, no matter how many ranges, if any, are in it.

I can't really come up with an idea, without making the data static (for example, splitting it into different columns).

The below function works on strings without any ranges

```
=LEN(TRIM(C10))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(C10);",";""))+1
```

but the main problem is that I have numbers like "1-5, 8, 10, 15" where it should return 8 as the amount of numbers in the cell.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4GWr.png]

Comment: The function you're using doesn't return 5?

Comment: It returns 5 when I put in "1,2,3,4,5", but I don't know how to handle "1-5", to return 5

Comment: https://prnt.sc/1qyyd00

Comment: What version of Excel have you got

Comment: I have the Excel 2019 version

Comment: ok - sorry - nevermind my solution...

Comment: I added a 2019 version - but you will have to convert , to ; as my version is comma based - sorry

Comment: I found a way to do it in one long formula with no less than 9 references to C10, but it has no helper cells and no VBA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest a User Defined Function written with VBA:

```
Function countNumbersInString(S As String) As Long

   Dim v, w, x, i As Long, col As Collection

v = Split(S, ",")

Set col = New Collection
    For Each w In v
        If w Like ("*-*") Then
             x = Split(w, "-")
             For i = x(0) To x(1)
                col.Add i
            Next i
        Else
            col.Add CLng(w)
        End If
    Next w

    countNumbersInString = col.Count
            
End Function
```

Comment: that really looks like the way to go in Excel 2019

Comment: Yup, as I thought the best way was using VBA. Thank you kindly for the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

OK - with Excel 2019 and the craziest formula ever:

```
=SUM( IF( ISTEXT(( FILTERXML( "<main><sub>" & SUBSTITUTE( C10, ",", "</sub><sub>" ) & "</sub></main>", "//sub" ) )), VALUE( RIGHT( ( FILTERXML( "<main><sub>" & SUBSTITUTE( C10, ",", "</sub><sub>" ) & "</sub></main>", "//sub" ) ), LEN( ( FILTERXML( "<main><sub>" & SUBSTITUTE( C10, ",", "</sub><sub>" ) & "</sub></main>", "//sub" ) ) ) - FIND( "-", ( FILTERXML( "<main><sub>" & SUBSTITUTE( C10, ",", "</sub><sub>" ) & "</sub></main>", "//sub" ) )) ) ) - VALUE(LEFT( ( FILTERXML( "<main><sub>" & SUBSTITUTE( C10, ",", "</sub><sub>" ) & "</sub></main>", "//sub" ) ), FIND( "-", ( FILTERXML( "<main><sub>" & SUBSTITUTE( C10, ",", "</sub><sub>" ) & "</sub></main>", "//sub" ) ) )-1 ) ) +  1, IF( YEAR( ( FILTERXML( "<main><sub>" & SUBSTITUTE( C10, ",", "</sub><sub>" ) & "</sub></main>", "//sub" ) ) ) > 1900, ABS( MONTH(( FILTERXML( "<main><sub>" & SUBSTITUTE( C10, ",", "</sub><sub>" ) & "</sub></main>", "//sub" ) ))-DAY( ( FILTERXML( "<main><sub>" & SUBSTITUTE( C10, ",", "</sub><sub>" ) & "</sub></main>", "//sub" ) ) ) ) +1, 1 ) ) )
```

Which is an expansion of:

```
=LET( string, C10,
       a, TRANSPOSE( FILTERXML( "<main><sub>" & SUBSTITUTE( C10, ",", "</sub><sub>" ) & "</sub></main>", "//sub" ) ),
       SUM( IF( ISTEXT(a), VALUE( RIGHT( a, LEN( a ) - FIND( "-", a) ) ) - VALUE(LEFT( a, FIND( "-", a )-1 ) ) +  1,
                            IF( YEAR( a ) > 1900, ABS( MONTH(a)-DAY(a ) ) +1, 1 ) ) )  )
```

Comment: That's one crazy formula! ++

Comment: @JvdV - exactly. I took the LET and jammed all of the variables (including your famous FILTERXML) into one line. I tried to maintain formatting, but eventually, that became a fool's errand. Pity that there needs to be a **,** to **;** conversion - that makes it all the worse for xda. It is a well posed and complex problem. I would like to think there is an elegant solution out there. What I learned here is that when you apply FILTERXML splitting, Excel converts `1-5` into 1 May (or 5 Jan)! That required the ridiculous Month and Day workaround.

Comment: There is a workaround for that particular issue yet in this particular case it's a nasty side-effect!

Comment: @JvdV - I was wondering it there was. It is an unfortunate behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the following:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>`"&SUBSTITUTE(A1;",";"</s><s>`")&"</s></t>";"//s[contains(.,'-')]");"-";REPT(" ";LEN(A1)));LEN(A1))-LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>+"&SUBSTITUTE(A1;",";"</s><s>+")&"</s></t>";"//s[contains(.,'-')]");"-";REPT(" ";LEN(A1)));LEN(A1))+1);0)+IFERROR(COUNT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1;",";"</s><s>")&"</s></t>";"//s[.*0=0]"));0)
```

Confirm as array-formula through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: I'm at 1033 :blush... if only SPLIT() was released. I know LAMBDA will make that possible, but... 2019.

Comment: @markfitzpatrick, I was able to cut this down to 376 chars and just three calls of `FILTERXML()`... =). A fun puzzle! A little trick to bypass the auto-date function of Excel was to add a "+"  in front of the elements in the array and therefor make use of the auto-add function of Excel when we minus the left part of the hyphen-delimited strings from the right one. So instead of biting us in the a$$ the auto-editing helps us out!

Comment: Oh - that's interesting. All points are really insightful. I can't believe that you got it down to 3 FILTERXMLs. I went full-Texas with 9.  I realized at one point that I had left a TRANSPOSE in it to align the arrays and did not remove it when it was no longer needed, but no matter how ridiculous it gets, keep plugging holes until it gives the right answer because I had already made the formula too unreadable to debug! :-D I was laughing out loud when it worked. Yours is elegant - nice work.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
=RIGHT(C10, LEN(C10)-SEARCH("-", C10))-
LEFT(C10, SEARCH("-", C10)-1)+1
```

[image]

Comment: Sadly It creates a new problem, because I have strings like "1-5,7,8" and It does not count them properly

Comment: @xda3213432 Is it always only 1 range (i.e. is there something like "1, 3-5, 7-10, 11, 12, 13-15")?

Comment: It varies. Here's an example https://prnt.sc/1qz28za

Comment: Okay, got it. Can you add as a picture instead of a link (or better yet a table we can copy and paste into excel) in the body of the original post?